# Convert .3GP to MP3?

Tags: audio, audio-recording

I recently recorded some audio on my cell phone that's a file type .3gp. Is there a way I can convert this to a more workable file type, such as MP3?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), a free command-line tool. Basic command is

```
ffmpeg -i file.3gp file.mp3
```